# Representing a has_many relationship in Rails with an abstract class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a relationship which I am having a hard time modelling.

I have a `Subscription` class which is a regular ActiveRecord model and it can have one or more `PaymentSources`. The problem however is that a payment source could refer to either a `CreditCard` or a `BankAccount`.

Given that these models have very different data associated with them I don't feel as though STI is a good option here. So I was wondering if there is an established or recommended approach for a situation in Rails where a model has_many of another model which is actually an abstraction for 2 or more classes which don't share the same data layout.

Ideally, in this particular example I could say something like `subscription.payment_source.default` and have it refer to either a `CreditCard` or a `BankAccount` depending on what the user had selected as their preferred billing method.

Comment: Did you read about [polymorphism](https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) before? I guess this gonna help u with this issue.
PaymentSource table gonna hold the `payable_id` and `payable_type` with additional boolean fields says if it is default and all you have to do is to add a `scope` which is gonna be called `default` and it returns the chosen default payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR:

[Updated] After some pondering, I will do Option 2 (the more complete solution) which is future-proof flexible, but if you don't need all of this complexity, I'll do just Option 1.

### Option 1:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :credit_card
  belongs_to :bank_account

  def payment_sources
    [credit_card, bank_account].compact
  end

  def default_payment_source
    case user.preferred_billing_method # assuming you have an integer column in users table called `preferred_billing_method`
    when 0 then credit_card # asssuming 0 means "Credit Card"
    when 1 then bank_account # assuming 1 means "Bank Account"
    else NotImplementedError
    end
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```
Subscription.first.default_payment_source
# => returns either `CreditCard` or `BankAccount`, or `nil`

Subscription.first.payment_sources.first
# => returns either `CreditCard` or `BankAccount`, or `nil`
```

### Option 2:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :default_payment_source, class_name: 'PaymentSource'
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :payment_sources_subscriptions
  has_many :payment_sources, through: :payment_sources_subscriptions
end

# This is just a join-model
class PaymentSourcesSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :payment_source

  validates :subscription, uniqueness: { scope: :payment_source }
end

# this is your "abstract" model for "payment sources"
class PaymentSource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payment_sourceable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :payment_sources_subscriptions
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :payment_sources_subscriptions

  validates :payment_sourceable, uniqueness: true
end

class CreditCard < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payment_source, as: :payment_sourceable
end

class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payment_source, as: :payment_sourceable
end
```

#### Usage:

```
User.first.default_payment_source.payment_sourceable
# => returns either `CreditCard` or `BankAccount`, or `nil`

Subscription.first.payment_sources.first.payment_sourceable
# => returns either `CreditCard` or `BankAccount`, or `nil`
```

Comment: If you do not know yet how to set up "polymorphic" tables, see [*documenation here*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)